# Does HTMLSession closes automatically?

Tags: python, python-requests-html

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
```

Does `session` closes automatically when an error occurs or do I need to close it by myself in the except bloc?

```
def hello():
    session = HTMLSession()
    raise Exception


try:
    hello()
except:
    session.close() # Do I need that?
```

**Edit: I tried the following:**

```
session = HTMLSession()
def hello():
    session = HTMLSession()
    print(session)
    raise Exception

try:
    hello()
except:
    print(session)
    session.close()
    print(session)
```

Output:

```
<requests_html.HTMLSession object at 0x107df59a0>
<requests_html.HTMLSession object at 0x1063dfcd0>
<requests_html.HTMLSession object at 0x1063dfcd0>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using session.close()
it will close only browser:

## this is the backend code of close:

```
def close(self):
        """ If a browser was created close it first. """
        if hasattr(self, "_browser"):
            self.loop.run_until_complete(self._browser.close())
        super().close()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJo0b.png)

and you getting memmory object create at you can delete this object after close

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session_o = HTMLSession()


def hello():  # sourcery skip: raise-specific-error
    session = HTMLSession()
    print(session)
    raise Exception


try:
    hello()
except:
    print(session_o)
    session_o.close()
    print(session_o)
    del session_o
    print(session_o)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two potential questions here.  One question is what happens if an exception is raised **by the `session` object**. That case is a bit interesting.  But with your code, you're not asking that question.  You're asking if raising and catching your own exception somehow affects the `session` object.

There's no reason to expect that anything would happen to the `session` object because your code threw an exception.  The exception has nothing to do with the `session` object.  Rather, your code threw it for no reason at all.  The `session` object never failed to do something, so from its point of view (and Python's), `session` was created and is still ready to do whatever it does.  An unrelated exception having been raised and caught does not impact the `session` object.  Why would it?

Raising an exception is not fundamentally different than any other program flow control statement, like a `while` loop or an `if/else`. It's a bit more complicated, but there's nothing at all special about using it. Upon `raise` being called,  the execution pointer is moved to another location (kinda like with a `break` in a `while` loop) and the exception that was raised is made available to the `except` code block.  That's it. There's no behind the scene magic.